# How can I perform a check before sbt assembly

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I would like to perform some checks before `sbt assembly` that make the build fail early when certain conditions are not met. What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assembly <<= assembly dependsOn myCheckTask
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, but I see now that the reason that this was not working is that I did this in the root of a multi-project build. Is there a way to set this in the root project, so that it applies to all children?

Comment: `dependsOn(myTask in sub1, myTask in sub2, myTask in subN,...)`

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm not following you correctly, but I want this the other way round: The assembly tasks in all sub projects should depend on single check task in the root project. Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Then `assembly in subN <<= (assembly in subN) dependsOn (myTask in root)` assuming you've named your root project, repeat for each subN